# How to configure Confluent.Kafka ProducerConfig for immediate message delivery without buffering?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm developing a .NET application using Confluent.Kafka for message communication. I need to configure the ProducerConfig in a way that messages are sent to Kafka instantly without buffering. Is there a setting similar to Flush() or an alternative approach to achieve this?

Can the parameter LingerMs = 0 help me?

```
var config = new ProducerConfig()
{
    BootstrapServers = uris,
    Acks = Acks.All,
    MessageSendMaxRetries = 0,
    MessageMaxBytes = 1024 * 1024 * maxMessageSize,
    LingerMs = 1
};
```